# Two inequalities with $e$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have problem because I can't do this exercise:

> Prove that: $\forall x>1$,
>   $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x<e<(1+\frac{1}{x-1})^x$
>
> and:  $\forall (p,q)>0$, $\left ( 1+\frac{p}{q} \right )^q\leq e^p \leq \left ( 1+\frac{p}{q} \right )^{p+q}$

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Note that $e\lt (1-\frac{1}{x-1})^x$ doesn't look right when $x\gt 1$.

Comment: Putting $x=2,e<(1-\frac1{2-1})^2=0??$

Comment: Probably it should be $\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^x$.

Comment: If you take logarithms in the first inequality, replace $x$ by $1/x$, and multiply by $x$, you see that you have to prove $\ln(1+x)<x$. But $y=x$ is the tangent at $x=1$ of $y=\ln(1+x)$, and the latter curve is concave, so that is not too hard. A similar strategy may well work on the other inequalities.

Comment: I edited the question to ask for a true inequality, as suggested by @WillOrrick. The edit also relates the two parts in a more meaningful way. If the exercise was given as originally posted, it is clearly a misprint. (Also, a correction to my previous comment: I should have said “tangent at $x=0$”.)

Comment: i reformulated the unequality. check if this is right now.

Comment: @miracle173 I don't see much sense in suggesting the same edit once again, after it already [had been rejected](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36872). Perhaps a better way would be suggesting different version of the inequality in a comment.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: I did not see that the edit was rejected. I thought i did not save the edit. Is there a way to se that the edit is rejected? There is nothing in the faq that covers this topic.

Comment: I think the second inequality could be $e<(1+1/x)^{x+1}$ then $\forall x>1$ can be changed to $\forall x>0$ as in the second inequality pair. This includes the original inequality and you can immediately see that the two inequality pairs are equivalent by taking the $p$-th root and subsituting $\frac{q}{p}$ by $x$ and changing the $\le$ by $\lt$.

Comment: @miracle173 See meta: [How to tell when suggested edits have been considered?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/how-to-tell-when-suggested-edits-have-been-considered). Other posts tagged [suggested-edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) might be useful to read, too.

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality follows from the second with $p=1$, if we'll prove it with $<$ instead of $\le$.

Taking a $p$'th root of the second inequality, it becomes:
$$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} < e < (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}+1}$$
Where $x=\frac{p}{q} >0$. Taking logarithm, it becomes
$$\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x) < 1 < (\frac{1}{x}+1)\ln(1+x)$$
or: $$ \ln(1+x) < x< (1+x)\ln(x+1)$$

This can be proved by showing $x-\ln(1+x), (1+x)\ln(1+x)-x$ are increasing:
$$(x-\ln(1+x))'=1-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{x}{x+1}>0 \implies $$ $$x-\ln(1+x) > 0 - \ln1  =0$$
$$((x+1)\ln(1+x)-x)'=\frac{x+1}{x+1}+\ln(x+1)-1 = \ln(x+1) > \ln 1 = 0 \implies $$ $$(x+1)\ln(1+x)-x > 1 \ln 1 - 0 = 0$$

As mentioned in the comments, this can be interpreted geometrically as follows: $\ln(1+x)$ is concave and $(1+x)\ln(1+x)$ is convex (with second derivative $\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2},\frac{1}{1+x}$ respectively), and $l(x) = x$ is tangent to both functions at $x=0$. The tangent to a convex graph is always below the graph, and for a concave graph it is always above. See this [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20ln%281%2bx%29,x,%281%2bx%29ln%281%2bx%29).

Answer (score 0):

Using the series
$$
-\log(1-u)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{u^k}{k}\tag{1}
$$
we get that
$$
\begin{align}
x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
&=(1-(x+1))\log\left(1-\frac1{x+1}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(x+1)^k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(x+1)^{k-1}}\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(x+1)^k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)(x+1)^k}\\
&=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)(x+1)^k}\\
&\lt1\quad\text{for }x\ge0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{align}
x\log\left(1+\frac1{x-1}\right)
&=-x\log\left(1-\frac1x\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{kx^{k-1}}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)x^k}\\
&\gt1\quad\text{for }x\gt1\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get that for $x\gt1$,
$$
\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\lt e\lt\left(1+\frac1{x-1}\right)^x\tag{4}
$$

---

Let $x=\frac qp$, then $(2)$ says that for $p,q\gt0$,
$$
\left(1+\frac pq\right)^{q/p}\lt e\tag{5}
$$
Let $x=1+\frac qp$, then $(3)$ says that for $p,q\gt0$,
$$
\left(1+\frac pq\right)^{(p+q)/p}\gt e\tag{6}
$$
Combining $(5)$ and $(6)$ says that for $p,q\gt0$
$$
\left(1+\frac pq\right)^q\lt e^p\lt\left(1+\frac pq\right)^{p+q}\tag{7}
$$